# Blender vertices on the inside (Solidify modifier)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, solidify-modifier

I'm following Blender Guru's blender 3.0 donut tutorial but there is something wrong with my icing.
I'm in *Edit Mode* but the vertices are on the inside (mine is upside down)
[image: My blender icing]

[image: His blender icing]

Comment: I took the freedom to edit your tags and the question since this has absolutely nothing to do with nodes.

Comment: To add to the other answers, maybe your normals are inverted?

Answer (score 3):

set solidify offset to 1.000 (-1.000 is the default)

Answer (score 2):

Andrew has disabled the modifier visibility for *Edit Mode* that's usually enabled by default, which means when he switches to *Edit Mode* he can only see the base mesh, not the thickness added by the modifier. He explains it after 1:05 in the video. I can only recommend to watch tutorials thoroughly to not miss any details.

[image: modifier visibility]

Answer (score 1):

Check your Normal direction. *Viewport overlays> Geometry: Face orientation*. Blue should be on the outside. If it's red on the outside, go to *Edit Mode*, select all vertices, and go to *Mesh > Normals > Flip*.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Solidify* modifier change the offset to -1.000